# polyline with label in javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

This is my code which is used to add a polyline ,but i want to add a label on click on polyline.When i click on the polyline,it shows a label .

```
      <script>
        var x=new google.maps.LatLng(52.395715,4.888916);
        var stavanger=new google.maps.LatLng(58.983991,5.734863);
      var amsterdam=new google.maps.LatLng(52.395715,4.888916);
           var london=new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850);

          function initialize()
            {
             var mapProp = {
                center:x,
                zoom:4,
              mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
              };

                  var map=new                            google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);

               var myTrip=[stavanger,amsterdam,london];
                     var flightPath=new google.maps.Polyline({
                    path:myTrip,
                  strokeColor:"#0000FF",
                   strokeOpacity:0.8,
                  strokeWeight:2
                 });

                        flightPath.setMap(map);
                  }

                  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
                  </script>
                   </head>

                     <body>
                     <div id="googleMap" style="width:500px;height:380px;"></div>
                     </body>
                  </html>
```

help me with how to add labels.

Comment: Here's [an article](https://duncan99.wordpress.com/2013/02/28/google-maps-api-polylines-and-events/) about how to add labels to polylines in response to user clicks

Comment: that is a nice article,can you share a link to add label on google maps using its lat/long??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, here's an example adapted from [the article I linked to](https://duncan99.wordpress.com/2013/02/28/google-maps-api-polylines-and-events/).  It displays the label at the point where you clicked.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Polyline with label on click</title>

<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<style type="text/css">
html { height: 100% }
body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
#map_canvas { height: 100% }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script>
// Define the overlay, derived from google.maps.OverlayView
function Label(opt_options) {
    // Initialization
    this.setValues(opt_options);

    // Label specific
    var span = this.span_ = document.createElement('span');
    span.style.cssText = 'position: relative; left: -50%; top: -8px; ' +
                         'white-space: nowrap; border: 1px solid blue; ' +
                         'padding: 2px; background-color: white';

    var div = this.div_ = document.createElement('div');
    div.appendChild(span);
    div.style.cssText = 'position: absolute; display: none';
}
Label.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();

// Implement onAdd
Label.prototype.onAdd = function() {
    var pane = this.getPanes().floatPane;
    pane.appendChild(this.div_);

    // Ensures the label is redrawn if the text or position is changed.
    var me = this;
    this.listeners_ = [
        google.maps.event.addListener(this, 'position_changed',
            function() { me.draw(); }),
        google.maps.event.addListener(this, 'text_changed',
            function() { me.draw(); })
    ];
};

// Implement onRemove
Label.prototype.onRemove = function() {
    var i, I;
    this.div_.parentNode.removeChild(this.div_);

    // Label is removed from the map, stop updating its position/text.
    for (i = 0, I = this.listeners_.length; i < I; ++i) {
        google.maps.event.removeListener(this.listeners_[i]);
    }
};

// Implement draw
Label.prototype.draw = function() {
    var projection = this.getProjection();
    var position = projection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.get('position'));

    var div = this.div_;
    div.style.left = position.x + 'px';
    div.style.top = position.y + 'px';
    div.style.display = 'block';

    this.span_.innerHTML = this.get('text').toString();
};

function initialize() {
    var stavanger=new google.maps.LatLng(58.983991,5.734863);
    var amsterdam=new google.maps.LatLng(52.395715,4.888916);
    var london=new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850);

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
        zoom: 5,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.395715,4.888916),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var myTrip=[stavanger,amsterdam,london];

    var flightPath=new google.maps.Polyline({
        path:myTrip,
        strokeColor:"#0000FF",
        strokeOpacity:0.8,
        strokeWeight:2,
        map:map
    });

    // create an invisible marker
    labelMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: stavanger,  
        map: map,
        visible: false
    });

    var myLabel = new Label();

    // lets add an event listener, if you click the line, i'll tell you the coordinates you clicked
    flightPath.addListener('click', function(e) {
        labelMarker.setPosition(e.latLng)
        myLabel.bindTo('position', labelMarker, 'position');
        myLabel.set('text', e.latLng.toString());
        myLabel.setMap(map);
    });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
</body>
</html>
```