# label a kml file in Google Maps API v3

Tags: google-maps-api-3, kml, label

I am trying to figure out how to use Google Maps API v3 to label a kml polyline that was originally created in ArcGIS Desktop.  Unfortunately, the examples that I came across thus far either don't seem to apply to kml files, had dead links, or were examples on how to create pop-ups.

If anyone has an example of how to create labels (not popups) from a kml file let me know.

Side questions:

*In ArcGIS I can use Layer->Properties->HTML Popup to configure the popup for kml.  What do I need to do in ArcGIS to specify what attribute I want to use as my label?

*Can I make labels appear only at certain resolutions?

Answer (score 3):

You can't add labels using the [Google Maps Javascript API KmlLayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/kmllayer), if your KML isn't too complicated, you can use a third party parser (like [geoxml3](https://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/) or [geoxml-v3](https://code.google.com/p/geoxml-v3/)) to render your KML as native Google Maps Javascript API v3 Polylines, and add labels to those.

labeling options:

- [polyline with label in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20654718/polyline-with-label-in-javascript)
- [MapLabel](https://github.com/googlemaps/js-map-label)
- [InfoBox](https://github.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/tree/master/infobox)